# Linking to a page from a button in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, button, onclick

I wasnt it so that the button "done" will be linked to a php file so that I can do some queries in it so by clikcing the button will do stuff to the content however I dont know how to link the file in javascript
Heres the code
var todo = {};

```
todo.txtNew = $('#txtNew');
todo.list = $("#lists");
todo.oldEntry = ''; // storage of old entry
todo.options = "<div class='ud'><a class='update'>Update</a><a class='delete'>Delete</a><a class='done'>Done </a></div>";
todo.form = "<form id='updateTextForm' action='' onsubmit='return false;'><input id='updateTextInput' type='text'/></form>";
```

How would I go about linking the "DONE" like an action in php? Is this possible?

Comment: So you just need to add a link to the Done "a" tag?

Comment: anchors usually have href's.

Comment: yes @Troy but anytime i just add an a href the JavaScript list can not be retrieved from database

Comment: @user3464354 I'm sorry but you are not clear enough.

Comment: @Troy Sorry, I would like the done button in the javascript to somehow update a value in one of the columns in the table of my database

Comment: You need to do some research on `ajax`. This will allow you to send paramters to a php script on the server and receive data back. This all happens without the page refreshing or submitting. I personally like to use JQuery for this but you can do it in raw javascript if you prefer.